# Running a py script as www-data from a cronjob fails, but running as a command through terminal works

Tags: permissions, cron

So, I have this script that needs to run every minute, so I set up a cronjob to run the script, lets say the command is:

```
/var/www/script.py
```

I use Webmin to setup the cronjob and set it to execute as www-data. I also use it to see the output when running the command.

When I execute the cronjob I get a permission error, when trying to create a file. But when I run the following command it works.

```
sudo -u www-data /var/www/script.py
```

Can anyone tell me why?

#### Update

The file it is trying to create is called `runnning.txt` and is placed next to the script (`/var/www/running.txt`)

The error the command generates when running as a cronjob

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/lager-scanner/filer/pluk_script.py", line 237, in <module>
    with open(filename, "w+") as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'running.txt'
```

The contents of `/etc/crontab`

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

Output of `sudo -u www-data crontab -l`

```
# * * * * * /var/www/script.py
```

I don't know how webmin does its thing. It's a webinterface, where I just select what user the command is supposed to be run by.

Comment: What file? Where? What exact error? What is the script doing? How does webmin tell it to run as `www-data`? Please [edit] your question and give us more details. Also show us the contents of `/etc/crontab`  and `sudo -u www-data crontab -l`.

Comment: Added the requested info

Comment: OK, it looks like webmnin creates a user crontab. Is the `#` really part of the output of `sudo -u www-data crontab -l`? Does it make any difference if you delete the `/var/www/running` file before cron runs the script? Also, what happens if you run `echo foo | sudo -u www-data tee /var/www/test`?

Comment: Yes the # is part of the output, but that might be because I disabled the job in webmin, because it doesn't work. The script creates the `running.txt` when it starts and deletes it when it is done. If I run the `echo foo | sudo -u www-data tee /var/www/test` I just get `foo` back.

Comment: When I enable the job and run `sudo -u www-data crontab -l`, I get `* * * * * /var/www/script.py`.

Comment: What's `stat /var/www` give you?  I'm guessing owned by root, and www-data has no rights to write running.txt.  I'd suggest changing the script to save the file elsewhere and try again.

Comment: Nope, it's www-data:www-data who owns that folder, just checked.